# Finding descendents in a self-referencial relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Image` model which `has_many` versions. A version is also an image, setup as a self-referential relation.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Image'
  has_many :versions, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

When a new image is created a callback searches the db for an image that has the same name. If it finds one, it will set its `parent_id` to the id of the new image. This creates a tree, structure:

```
| id | name  | parent_id |
--------------------------
|  1 | a.gif |         2 |
|  2 | a.gif |         3 |
|  3 | a.gif |      NULL |
--------------------------
```

Is there an easy way to retrieve all the descendents of an image? `image.versions` finds image with id 2, as expected. To get image with id 1 I have to go through image 2.

```
image = Image.find(3)
versions = image.versions # this finds image 2
descendents = versions.each { |v| v.versions } # etc...
```

I tried with a `has_one` relation:

```
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Image'
  has_one :version, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :versions, through: :version
```

That still only retrieves image with id 2, and not the entire tree of descents. I have two known choices:

1. Use the callback to update all images with the same name, but I would rather not use more complex callbacks.
2. Use a separate table to store versions. But this is complex for two reasons.

   1. Because I track all activity on Image, by transforming an Image into an ImageVersion its references will be lost in the Activity table (it's class and id would have changed).
   2. People create multiple new images at once (they don't update one by one), and it's only after they're inserted that I can do versioning, which is an expensive process. This means by default new images will be created. Transforming them to versions and updating an original is proving very troublesome because of the mechanics of the uploads.

Comment: I would not make this a self referential but rather have an `Image` class and an `ImageVersion` class. This will make the logic a lot simpler as well as tracking decedents. Then an `Image` would have many `:image_versions` and you could manage the relationship in that table instead. Right now technically image 2 is the only other version of image 3 because image 1 is a version of image 2 this is more like an ancestry at this point.

Comment: I think you have your parent_id assignment wrong. If you do a.gif id with an id of 1, then you revise it, and that current image does not have any previous revisions, then you would create your new image with parent_id = 1, then your following revisions can look to see if it has a parent_id and would then match it.

To restate, an original file shouldn't have a parent_id. revisions should have a parent_id. Any revision on a revision would take the parent_id of the previous revision.

Comment: @engineersmnky that my my initial idea, but I can't create a separate model because I have an Activity model that tracks everything that happens on an image. By transforming Image to ImageVersion, I have to find all Activity belonging to the old image and make it reference the ImageVersion. It's possible since Activity is polymorphic, but more complex than this solution.

Comment: @aaron.v I understand that, but users can bulk upload images, and due to technical limitations we are only able to determine if an image exists after the save has happened. Inserting a new image then transforming it into a version and updating an original is too expensive to happen in real time, when people upload 20, 40, and even 100 files.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton even for revision uploading? You wouldn't have to do any changes for a bulk original upload, but to revise an image (which I would assume is a one image upload at a time), you would just have to have a parent_id set in the form for your revised image upload. How else could you know that an image upload is for a revision or not?

Comment: @aaron.v individual updates are fine. I can handle those easily. It's when a user uploads 50 files at once. Some of those may be new, some may have existing originals that must be updated to reflect the new file. I have reasonable way of preventing the user from throwing 50 files into the upload. I think it might be best to just use the callback to update the grandchild, that way we never have the tree situation.

Comment: @aaron.v I meant to say I have *no* reasonable way of preventing them...

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that you should be moving the ImageVersion to a new model instead of creating this tree.

It would simplify things and it would be (in my opinion) a better approach.

But if you really need to do this you should check out this gem, I've never used it but it seems to be exactly what you are asking for: https://github.com/take-five/activerecord-hierarchical_query

Hope it helps.

Comment: See my comments on my question. I can't do this because I'm tracking activity.

Comment: Then maybe that gem could help you querying your database